# How to echo the name of the column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, html-table

How to echo the name of the columns?. I was able to select and echo the content (td) but I don't know how to "load value" in the th. I mean to load from MySql database dynamically.

I want to "load value" from the same place that the td, from the database eee. I want to show the field name: id, a, b, c

```
<table>

<tr>
    <th><input class="gris" type="text" name="a" value="load value"/></td>
    <th><input class="gris" type="text" name="b" value="load value"/></td>
    <th><input class="gris" type="text" name="c" value="load value"/></td>
    <th><input class="gris" type="text" name="d" value="load value"/></td>
</tr>

<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eee");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
?>
<tr>
    <td> <input class="blanc" type="text" name="num" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"/> </td>
    <td><input class="blanc" type="text" name="primer" value="<?php echo $row['a']?>"/></td>
    <td><input class="blanc" type="text" name="segon" value="<?php echo $row['b']?>"/></td>
    <td><input class="blanc" type="text" name="segon" value="<?php echo $row['c']?>"/></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: from where are you getting this "load value"

Comment: are you want to show fields name ?

Comment: You can also use `mysql_field_name()`

Comment: I want to "load value" from the same place that the td, from the database eee. I want to show the field name: id, a, b, c

Comment: Please note: Mysql extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Might sound stupid, but why don't you write them down by yourself? You know the columns since you're using their name to fetch the values, and columns won't change, so.. just write <th>ID</th> <th>Primer</th> and so on

Comment: I simplified the problem here just to explain. In the future the user will have to add new columns, and I will not know the names that the user will choose.

Comment: User adding columns to a table smells like bad database design, though

Comment: I am learning php. It is not recommended that the user could add columns? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very new in php. I tried hard all the answers here but it did not work. Possibly because there is something I don't undersdand. Everybody here knows much more than me. After trying a lot of things I checked that this works:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM eee');
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {   
?>

<tr>
<th><input class="gris" type="text" name="<?php echo $property->name ?>" value="<?php echo $property->name ?>"/></th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for each on the $row array to get key/value pairs.  The Key should contain the column name from the table.  Note, that the default for mysql_fetch_array returns an array that has both associative AND indexed values as well, just incase you run into some kind of unexpected issues.  But I'm 90% certain all you have to do is a foreach with the $key => $value combo as shown here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Here's the page on mysql_fetch_array:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

More explicit explanation:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    /*  echo your table row with the $key and $value here. */
}
```

Comment: there's also a mysql_fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 1):

You could [`describe`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) the table at the cost of another query.

```
<tr>
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("DESCRIBE eee");
    $inputName = "a";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
?> 
    <th>
       <input class="gris" 
               type="text" 
               name="<?php echo inputName; ?>"     <!-- Generates unique names for the inputs too -->
               value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"/>
    </th>
<?php $inputName++; } ?>

</tr>
```

Comment: Why can't we use `mysql_field_name()` ? Any specific reason to use `DESCRIBE` ?

Comment: Simply because I didn't know about it. This is just what I've used in the past. Please post the better answer.

Comment: If I copy paste this to my code, it does not work. Probably I don't understand it well. Can you explain it or adapt it to my question please?

Comment: Did you change 'eee' to your table name?

Comment: @James: I cannot see the name of the columns. Probably is my fault, there must be something I do wrong.

Comment: @Damien: Yes, the real table name is eee

Answer (score 0):

Just write simple the column names as u already know the names..

```
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_NAME ='eee'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))  {
 ?>




<th><input class="gris" type="text" name="<?php echo $row['COLUMN_NAME ']?>" value="<?php echo $row['COLUMN_NAME ']?>"/></th>

<?php } ?>
</tr>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eee");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
 ?>
<tr>
<td> <input class="blanc" type="text" name="num" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"/> </td>
<td><input class="blanc" type="text" name="primer" value="<?php echo $row['primer']?>"/>          </td>
<td><input class="blanc" type="text" name="segon" value="<?php echo $row['segon']?>"/></td>
<td><input class="blanc" type="text" name="segon" value="<?php echo $row['tercer']?>"/>     </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: that is the question: I don't know the names I want to load the field name  dynamically

Comment: @Nrc you know the names, you're using them to get the values!

Comment: I simplified the problem here just to explain. In the future the user will have to add new columns, and I will not know the names that the user will choose.

Comment: use this query to retrive column names :-

SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';

Comment: I don't know where to write this. Can you edit your answer please?

Comment: @Nipun: thank you so much but with that code I cannot see the name of the columns. Perhaps there is something that I am missing.

Comment: No, it does not work. I added: <tr> that I think was missing before the th, but it does not work either. Anyway, thank you!